# ListView in Fragment not refreshed

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I created a tabbed app where the main acitvity contains two layouts. The top layout contains the actual tabbar (which is a fragment). Underneth the content layout contains another fragments depending on which tabbar button the user has clicked. In order to stay compatible with older android versions I use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

So, in the tabbar menu I added two buttons and each button triggers another fragment in the content. This is what the code looks like:

```
public class TabbarMenuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    LiveFragment liveFragment;
    OddsFragment oddsFragment;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    Button liveButton;
    Button oddsButton;

    public TabbarMenuFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        liveFragment = new LiveFragment();
        oddsFragment = new OddsFragment();
        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_view, oddsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        View rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabbar_menu, container, false);

        liveButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.liveButton);
        liveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        oddsButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.oddsButton);
        oddsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }



    public void updateUIInTabs() {
        liveFragment.updateUI();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == liveButton) {
            fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_view, liveFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if(v == oddsButton) {
            fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_view, oddsFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        updateUIInTabs();
    }
}
```

The important thing is that the `liveFragment` is a `Fragment` that contains a `ListView`:

```
public class LiveFragment extends Fragment {

    LiveMainAdapter adapter;
    ListView list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View rootView;

    public LiveFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_fragment, container, false);

        adapter = new LiveMainAdapter(inflater);
        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.live_fragment_ListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setDivider(null);
        list.setDividerHeight(0);

        return rootView;
    }


    public void updateUI() {
        if(list != null) {
            list.invalidate();
            adapter.createRowObjects();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

The `oddsFragment` is so far just a dummy with a `TextView`:

```
public class OddsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.odds_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Now there are two settings which are important:

First:

As described above: I start the app and the `oddsFragment` is initally shown. Now, when I click on the `liveFragment` button the `liveFragment`'s `ListView` is not updated. 
Clicking again on the button for `oddsFragment` the `oddsFragment` is properly shown. Clicking back to `liveFragment` I get nothing - no `ListView` is shown.

The second setting:

Is exactly the same as the first, but instead I set the `liveFragment` as the intial view that is in `TabbarMenuFragment` I replace:

```
fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_view, oddsFragment);
```

with

```
fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_view, liveFragment);
```

Then the `ListView` is properly shown and the data in the list view is updated and displayed correctly. However, if I click on `oddsFragement` and then again on `liveFragement` the `ListView` has disappeared.

I already tried different things for over two hours now and I'm pretty desperated because I have not clue what might be the reason for this wired behaviour.

Anybody got an idea what is going on here?

Comment: try to setAdapter in on resume of the fragment see if it helps,

Comment: Daniel, oh man, that was it. Thank you so much :). Please write an answer which I then can accept.

Comment: That is just a lazy solution, the correct method should not be this way, you should set the adapter once, and call notifyDataSetChanged like you did, So I will not bother with making it an official answer :) Also I would like to add that notifityDataSetChange from what I remember should be called on the ListView itself or inside the fragment somewhere since the adapter is there just to tell the list how to render its content, its the list that call the adapter so calling datasetchange on the adapter will do nothing, not sure though

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

In your `LiveFragment` add a `Handler` and a `Runnable` and update the UI from your Runnable.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable updater = new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    if(list != null) {
        list.invalidate();
        adapter.createRowObjects();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
};
```

and then change your `updateUI()` method in  `LiveFragment`

```
public void updateUI()
{
  handler.post(updater);
}
```

Comment: Yeah. This works also well. Thanks! However, as Daniel pointed, a simple `updateUI()` call in the `public void onResume()` method also does the job.